# Reading formatted string data using sscanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have a below code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char tempBuf[100] = {"|BOD|01|02|100|ID000001|EOD|"};
    char startSentinel[10], endSentinel[10], s1[10], s2[10], s3[10], s4[10];
    sscanf((char *)tempBuf, "|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|", startSentinel, s1, s2, s3, s4, endSentinel);

    cout<<startSentinel<<" "<<s1<<" "<<s2<<" "<<s3<<" "<<s4<<" "<<endSentinel;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints correct data.
Output: `BOD 01 02 100 ID000001 EOD`

---

If I modify the line to below:

```
char tempBuf[100] = {"|BOD|||100|ID000001|EOD|"};
```

Output: Garbage output.

---

If I give spaces as shown:

```
char tempBuf[100] = {"|BOD| | |100|ID000001|EOD|"}; //Inserted space.
```

Output is correct:

```
BOD     100 ID000001 EOD
```

Can anyone tell me why? And how can I get correct output without inserting space?

Comment: I guess you wanted to use the C++ tag.

Comment: Because `%[^|]` rejects `|`.

Comment: The scan set must match at least one character, not zero or more.  So adjacent pipes cause it to fail.  You would know if you'd tested the return value of `sscanf()`.  You can't use `sscanf()` to read possibly zero-length fields.  You'll have to rethink your approach.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so what can I use so not to reject |?

Comment: You can't use `strtok()`; it treats adjacent delimiters as a single delimiter.  So, you probably use `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`, or a variant on `strtok()` that doesn't treat adjacent delimiters as a single delimiter such as `strsep()`, if it is available.

Comment: Scan with division or Use `strsep` instead of `sscanf`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is no need for the cast `(char *)tempBuf` in the call to `sscanf()`, since array names decay to pointers in function calls (and in most expressions). The trouble is that the scanset `[^|]` matches *one or more* characters which are not `'|'`; when no such match occurs, the match fails and `sscanf()` returns.

The easiest solution would be to use the BSD (including macOS) and Linux function [`strsep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) to parse the input string into tokens. Since this function modifies the input string, you may want to use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) (POSIX) to make a duplicate of the original string to work with. `strdup()` uses `malloc()` to allocate memory for the duplicate string, so this will need to be `free`d after use. Also, a feature test macro may be needed to enable these functions.

Note that `strsep()` returns an empty string when two delimiters are found next to each other. In the code below, the first character is assumed to be a delimiter, and it is skipped over. Some changes would need to be made to handle less strictly formatted input.

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char tempBuf[100] = {"|BOD|||100|ID000001|EOD|"};
    char startSentinel[10], endSentinel[10], s1[10], s2[10], s3[10], s4[10];
    char *delims = "|";
    char *string = strdup(tempBuf);
    char *next = string + 1;            // skip first delimiter
    char *token;

    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(startSentinel, token, 10);
    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s1, token, 10);
    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s2, token, 10);
    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s3, token, 10);
    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s4, token, 10);
    token = strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(endSentinel, token, 10);

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", startSentinel, s1, s2, s3, s4, endSentinel);

    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

If the `strsep()` and `strdup()` functions are not available, they can be simply implemented, leaving the fundamental code above unchanged:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * my_strdup(const char *);
char * my_strsep(char **, const char *);

int main(void)
{
    char tempBuf[100] = {"|BOD|||100|ID000001|EOD|"};
    char startSentinel[10], endSentinel[10], s1[10], s2[10], s3[10], s4[10];
    char *delims = "|";
    char *string = my_strdup(tempBuf);
    char *next = string + 1;            // skip first delimiter
    char *token;

    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(startSentinel, token, 10);
    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s1, token, 10);
    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s2, token, 10);
    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s3, token, 10);
    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(s4, token, 10);
    token = my_strsep(&next, delims);
    strncpy(endSentinel, token, 10);

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", startSentinel, s1, s2, s3, s4, endSentinel);

    free(string);

    return 0;
}

char * my_strdup(const char *str)
{
    char *dup = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    char *c = dup;

    if (dup) {
        while (*str != '\0') {
            *c++ = *str++;
        }
        *c = '\0';
    }

    return dup;
}

char * my_strsep(char **strp, const char *delims)
{
    char *tok = NULL;

    if (*strp) {
        char *end = strpbrk(*strp, delims);

        if (end) {
            *end = '\0';
            tok = *strp;
            *strp = end + 1;
        }
    }

    return tok;
}
```

Both of the above programs give output:

```
BOD   100 ID000001 EOD
```

Comment: Note that `strsep()` is a BSD (macOS) and Linux function; it is not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm).  Also, where is `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` defined?  It isn't in POSIX or on macOS (BSD).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- Thanks for the comments and the edit. I misread the glibc manual, which places `strtok_r()` before `strsep()`; the last sentence says that `strtok_r()` is POSIX, and I managed to bleed this into my reading of the `strsep()` entry! I found `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` on the Linux man page for [`strsep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html); there is also an entry about it in the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros).

Comment: I compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, and had to include the feature test macro to avoid an error.

Comment: The `_xyz_SOURCE` macros are a never-ending cause of complexity.  There's `_POSIX_SOURCE` (deprecated), `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`: these are mandated by the POSIX and X/Open standards.  Then there are `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_GNU_SOURCE` that define extra material on BSD and GNU systems.  There's `__EXTENSIONS__` on Solaris, and probably others on other systems.  I'd not seen `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` before; it just adds to the confusion.  Follow the man page — but no enabling macro is required for `strsep()` on BSD. Ain't life fun.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- I tried `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` before looking it up; I guess that should have clued me in that `strsep()` is not POSIX. Sometimes I daydream about switching over to BSD; I wonder if the situation is better there, or just different.... ;)

Comment: Just different — nothing in life is quite that simple.